# Safari Extension, pass variable to new window

Tags: safari-extension

My extension opens a new safari window:

```
safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url =  safari.extension.baseURI + "popup.html"
```

And I have to pass selected word on the current page to this new window.

In Chrome I can do it in simple way:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
```

Does Safari have something like this? My background page has this data but I don't understand how to call background page from a new Safari window.

Thanks.

Comment: for reference, here's a great tutorial on building safari extensions. I've been building one and the docs and samples frankly suck... this is the best thing I've found. great. http://arstechnica.com/apple/2010/06/safari-5-extensions-how-to-develop/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() is

```
safari.extension.globalPage
```

Comment: In my case I couldn't access `safari.extension.globalPage` from inside a tab containing an extension page.
`safari.extension` is available, but not the `globalPage`, as docs say, it is only accesible from Bars and Popovers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH16-SW7